# ASP.NET Button not triggered inside a Bootstrap 3 Modal

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Trying to make a login form inside a Bootstrap 3 Modal, but the login button doesn't do any postback.
The most weird thing is that i have used Bootstrap Modal before in similar situations with no problems.

Here's my code:

```
<div id="modalLogin" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
            </div>


            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="form-horizontal">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="tbLoginEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbLoginEmail" TextMode="Email" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Email" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-1 error-message">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvLoginEmail" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="tbLoginEmail" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="tbLoginPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbLoginPassword" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Password" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-1 error-message">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvLoginPassword" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="tbLoginPassword" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <asp:Button ID="btLogin" Text="Login" CssClass="btn btn-standard" runat="server" OnClick="btLogin_Click" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

C# Code:

```
protected void btLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ///validate user credentials in membership
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(tbLoginEmail.Text, tbLoginPassword.Text))
    {
        ///login user to application
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(tbLoginEmail.Text, true);

        ///redirect to catalog page (TODO: redirect user to profile page)
        Response.RedirectToRoute("catalog-page");
    }
    else
    {
        lbResult.Text = "error";
    }
}
```

I'm using ASP.NET Web Forms 4.5 and the Modal is in the MasterPage.

Comment: no error in browser console? post all your markup please

Comment: @infer-on there are no errors in the browser console. i've tested the model outside the masterpage and it works well, but then the modal code is inside the masterpage the button doesn't work at all. here is my Default.master code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EwHzA?editors=100

Comment: Can you post the btLogin_Click method aswell?

Comment: @Brunis the code is strait forward: `protected void btLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ///validate user credentials in membership
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(tbLoginEmail.Text, tbLoginPassword.Text))
        {
            ///login user to application
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(tbLoginEmail.Text, true);

            ///redirect to catalog page (TODO: redirect user to profile page)
            Response.RedirectToRoute("catalog-page");
        }
        else
        {
            lbResult.Text = "Error";
        }
    }`

Comment: as i said, this works when i place the modal html markup ouside the master page (in the content page).

Comment: Edit your question and post the code there please :)

Comment: @brunis event code added :)

Comment: why do you not have a form that in your layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out my problem! i'm using validation controls not only in the login form, but in the register form as well. Since both the forms are in the master page if one of them is empty any button in the page will no be submitted.
To resolve my issue (i know, a rookie mistake), i added a validation group to each form - Login and Register.
Sorry for any inconvenience...